# How to get user ID from customer_register_success event in Magento?

Tags: magento, events

My observer is listening to the event **customer_register_success**.

When a new user registers a new account I only get the session ID and not the user ID. How can I get both the session ID and user ID?

**The way I'm retrieving the information about the customer who has registered:**

```
public function getUserReg($observer){

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    $session_id = $session->getEncryptedSessionId();

    $customer_data = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $user_id = $customer_data->entity_id;

    Mage::log("User Registration SESSION: " . $session_id, null, 't.log');
    Mage::log("User Registration USER: " . $user_id, null, 't.log');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the newly created customer object in Observer like below:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
```

Comment: I was able to get the user ID by adding **->entity_id** to the code You provided.

Comment: great. you can call like this way also: `->getId()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RegisterSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customerID = $customer->getId();
        $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstName();
    }
}
```